cURL returning 404 Not found while website is running in browser | nginx version: nginx/1.24.0
Very new to web development so I apologise in advance for any stupid questions...
I've recently deployed nginx/1.24.0 on an Amazon EC2 free tier instance and I have a plain index.html static message up. HTTPS is using Let's Encrypt / CertBot cert.
The website works, everything's displayed just fine. However, whenever I curl either the 127.0.0.1, my domain name or my external IP address, I get this:
`curl -v 127.0.0.1:80
 Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
 Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: 127.0.0.1
 User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 Server: nginx/1.24.0
 Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2024 20:05:56 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Length: 153
 Connection: keep-alive
 404 Not Found
 <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
 <hr>nginx/1.24.0
 * Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact`


`curl -v 127.0.0.1:443
 Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
 Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 443
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: 127.0.0.1:443
 User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
 Accept: */*

 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Server: nginx/1.24.0
 Date: Sat, 13 Jul 2024 20:24:24 GMT
 Content-Type: text/html
 Content-Length: 255
 Connection: close

 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
 <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
 <hr>nginx/1.24.0
 * Closing connection`

Here's my nginx.conf file located in /etc/nginx. I have no file located in conf.d nor in default.d folders. Also, I have no sited-enabled nor sites-available folders.
` access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 4096;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.m*********.com
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.m**********.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.m**********.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

`
If there's more info I need to provide, I'd be more than happy to do so.
Thanking you in advance for your help!
I have tried looking for another .conf file anywhere but I cannot find one.

Just tested from the outside and it works. It simply does not work from the local machine.
